# Deleting rows in dataframe with condition (function)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How do I write a function that deletes rows in my dataframe where the timedifference between two rows is less then 2 minutes nad how do I add rows if the timediff. is larger than 2?

This is what i've done so far:

```
data = []
with open("bird_jan25jan16.txt") as f: 
    for line in f:  
        try:
            date_str, time, movement = line.split()
            dt_str = date_str + ' ' + time
            dt = datetime.strptime(dt_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") 
            data.append([dt, movement]) 
        except ValueError:
            # Handle lines with unexpected format
            print(f"Ignoring line: {line}")

# Create a DataFrame from the data list
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Datetime", "Movement"]) 

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)

def preprocess_incomplete_counts(line):
    try:
        date_str, time, movement = line.split() 
        dt_str = date_str + ' ' + time
        dt = datetime.strptime(dt_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        return [dt, movement]          
    except ValueError:
        # Handle lines with incomplete counts, kan den ej konvertera lägger den
        #ej in i listan data =[]
        return None

#Does not work
def preprocess_missing_data(prev_dt, curr_dt, movement):
    data = []
    time_diff = (curr_dt - prev_dt).total_seconds() / 60.0
    if time_diff > 2:   
        for i in range(1, int(time_diff // 2)):
            intermediate_dt = prev_dt + pd.DateOffset(minutes=i * 2)
            data.append([intermediate_dt, None])
    data.append([curr_dt, movement])
    return data
```

Comment: I would use pandas `diff` function and then filter based on its' value

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html should be of help here. Create a series with a fixed interval (2mins) covering the range of your dataframe, merge it with your dataframe with a 2min tolerance, use forward direction here

Comment: Did this code, but I get an attribute error that list has no attribute "diff"

Comment: Did this code, but I get an attribute error that list has no attribute "diff"

Comment: Can you add some example data and expected output? I.e. if you have three observations each within a minute of each other do they become one observation or is the 2 minute window supposed to be fixed?